# Jquery can't set background-color use css("background-color","#fde3e5!important")

Tags: jquery, html

I use this code to set td's background-color:
[image]

```
$(function(){
$("#table_reach_condition_appoint tbody tr").each(function(){
        if($.trim($(this).children("td").eq(1).children("input").val())==""){
            $(this).children("td").eq(1).css("background-color","#fde3e5!important");
        }
        if($.trim($(this).children("td").eq(3).children("input").val())==""){
            $(this).children("td").eq(3).css("background-color","#fde3e5!important");
        }
        if($.trim($(this).children("td").eq(5).children("input").val())==""){
            $(this).children("td").eq(5).css("background-color","#fde3e5!important");
        }
    });
});
```

But there is no effect,where is wrong?
My html's code is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/2q6rg5pk/).

Comment: Remove the `!important` flag. It's not supported in jQuery's `css()` method. After that your code works, you just can't see the background as the `input` fill the full `td`. With some padding you'll see it: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/2q6rg5pk/5/. I would also suggest you look in to DRYing up your code, as you can make that about 25% of its current length

Comment: If I don't use padding: 5px,is there any other way？

Comment: You could set the background colour on the `input` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are assigning same background color to all the selected `<td>`, it is appropriate to use a class instead of assigning separate css to each `<td>`.

```js
$(function(){
$("#table_reach_condition_appoint tbody tr").each(function(){      if($.trim($(this).children("td").eq(1).children("input").val())==""){
            $(this).children("td").eq(1).addClass("tdClass");
        }
        if($.trim($(this).children("td").eq(3).children("input").val())==""){
            $(this).children("td").eq(3).addClass("tdClass");
        }
        if($.trim($(this).children("td").eq(5).children("input").val())==""){
            $(this).children("td").eq(5).addClass("tdClass");
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.tdClass{
  background-color: #fde3e5 !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head> 
  <meta charset="utf-8" /> 
  <title>111</title> 
  <script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script>
$(function(){

$("#table_reach_condition_appoint tbody tr").each(function(){
  if($.trim($(this).children("td").eq(1).children("input").val())==""){
   $(this).children("td").eq(1).css("background-color","#fde3e5!important");
  }
  if($.trim($(this).children("td").eq(3).children("input").val())==""){
   $(this).children("td").eq(3).css("background-color","#fde3e5!important");
  }
  if($.trim($(this).children("td").eq(5).children("input").val())==""){
   $(this).children("td").eq(5).css("background-color","#fde3e5!important");
  }
 });
});
</script>

 </head> 
 <body> 
<div id="inner_div_reach_condition_appoint" class="panel-body">
        <table id="table_reach_condition_appoint" border="1" class="table table-bordered text-right">
          <thead>
            <tr class="table-thead-tr">
              <th class="text-center">No</th>
              <th colspan="4" class="text-center">AA</th>

              <th class="text-center">BB</th>
              <th class="text-center"></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th style="display:none;"></th>
              <th style="display:none;"></th>
              <th style="display:none;"></th>
              <th style="display:none;"></th>
              <th style="display:none;"></th>
              <th style="display:none;"></th>
              <th style="display:none;"></th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody id ="tbody_reach_condition_appoint">
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>
                <input type="text" onkeyup="value=value.replace(/[^\d{1,}\.\d{1,}|^\d{1,}\%|\d{1,}]/g,'')"/> 
              </td>
              <td class="text-center disabledItemBgColor">
                <span>before</span>
              </td>
              <td class="text-center">
                <input type="text" onkeyup="value=value.replace(/[^\d{1,}\.\d{1,}|^\d{1,}\%|\d{1,}]/g,'')"/>
              </td>
              <td class="text-center disabledItemBgColor">
               <span>go</span>
              </td>
              <td>
                <input type="text" onkeyup="value=value.replace(/[^\d{1,}\.\d{1,}|^\d{1,}\%|\d{1,}]/g,'')"/>
              </td>
              <td>
                <span class="deleteRow" onclick="delRow(this,'#table_reach_condition_appoint')">✖</span>
              </td>
            </tr>
   <tr>
              <td>2</td>
              <td>
                <input type="text" onkeyup="value=value.replace(/[^\d{1,}\.\d{1,}|^\d{1,}\%|\d{1,}]/g,'')"/> 
              </td>
              <td class="text-center disabledItemBgColor">
                <span>before</span>
              </td>
              <td class="text-center">
                <input type="text" onkeyup="value=value.replace(/[^\d{1,}\.\d{1,}|^\d{1,}\%|\d{1,}]/g,'')"/>
              </td>
              <td class="text-center disabledItemBgColor">
               <span>go</span>
              </td>
              <td>
                <input type="text" onkeyup="value=value.replace(/[^\d{1,}\.\d{1,}|^\d{1,}\%|\d{1,}]/g,'')"/>
              </td>
              <td>
                <span class="deleteRow" onclick="delRow(this,'#table_reach_condition_appoint')">✖</span>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div> 
 </body>
</html>
```

If you want to use the existing code then you can remove the `!important` from the `css` method as it is not supported.

```js
$(function(){
$("#table_reach_condition_appoint tbody tr").each(function(){
        if($.trim($(this).children("td").eq(1).children("input").val())==""){
            $(this).children("td").eq(1).css("background-color","#fde3e5");
        }
        if($.trim($(this).children("td").eq(3).children("input").val())==""){
            $(this).children("td").eq(3).css("background-color","#fde3e5");
        }
        if($.trim($(this).children("td").eq(5).children("input").val())==""){
            $(this).children("td").eq(5).css("background-color","#fde3e5");
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head> 
  <meta charset="utf-8" /> 
  <title>111</title> 
  <script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script>
$(function(){

$("#table_reach_condition_appoint tbody tr").each(function(){
  if($.trim($(this).children("td").eq(1).children("input").val())==""){
   $(this).children("td").eq(1).css("background-color","#fde3e5!important");
  }
  if($.trim($(this).children("td").eq(3).children("input").val())==""){
   $(this).children("td").eq(3).css("background-color","#fde3e5!important");
  }
  if($.trim($(this).children("td").eq(5).children("input").val())==""){
   $(this).children("td").eq(5).css("background-color","#fde3e5!important");
  }
 });
});
</script>

 </head> 
 <body> 
<div id="inner_div_reach_condition_appoint" class="panel-body">
        <table id="table_reach_condition_appoint" border="1" class="table table-bordered text-right">
          <thead>
            <tr class="table-thead-tr">
              <th class="text-center">No</th>
              <th colspan="4" class="text-center">AA</th>

              <th class="text-center">BB</th>
              <th class="text-center"></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th style="display:none;"></th>
              <th style="display:none;"></th>
              <th style="display:none;"></th>
              <th style="display:none;"></th>
              <th style="display:none;"></th>
              <th style="display:none;"></th>
              <th style="display:none;"></th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody id ="tbody_reach_condition_appoint">
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>
                <input type="text" onkeyup="value=value.replace(/[^\d{1,}\.\d{1,}|^\d{1,}\%|\d{1,}]/g,'')"/> 
              </td>
              <td class="text-center disabledItemBgColor">
                <span>before</span>
              </td>
              <td class="text-center">
                <input type="text" onkeyup="value=value.replace(/[^\d{1,}\.\d{1,}|^\d{1,}\%|\d{1,}]/g,'')"/>
              </td>
              <td class="text-center disabledItemBgColor">
               <span>go</span>
              </td>
              <td>
                <input type="text" onkeyup="value=value.replace(/[^\d{1,}\.\d{1,}|^\d{1,}\%|\d{1,}]/g,'')"/>
              </td>
              <td>
                <span class="deleteRow" onclick="delRow(this,'#table_reach_condition_appoint')">✖</span>
              </td>
            </tr>
   <tr>
              <td>2</td>
              <td>
                <input type="text" onkeyup="value=value.replace(/[^\d{1,}\.\d{1,}|^\d{1,}\%|\d{1,}]/g,'')"/> 
              </td>
              <td class="text-center disabledItemBgColor">
                <span>before</span>
              </td>
              <td class="text-center">
                <input type="text" onkeyup="value=value.replace(/[^\d{1,}\.\d{1,}|^\d{1,}\%|\d{1,}]/g,'')"/>
              </td>
              <td class="text-center disabledItemBgColor">
               <span>go</span>
              </td>
              <td>
                <input type="text" onkeyup="value=value.replace(/[^\d{1,}\.\d{1,}|^\d{1,}\%|\d{1,}]/g,'')"/>
              </td>
              <td>
                <span class="deleteRow" onclick="delRow(this,'#table_reach_condition_appoint')">✖</span>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div> 
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: When I use addClass,I still can't see the background color.Why?

Comment: @MadFrog the snippet above works. In that case, you need to create a JSfiddle of your complete code to check, And by the way did you add `.tdClass{
  background-color: #fde3e5 !important;
}` in css?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `odd` or `even` jquery selector which will select rows as per odd or even index inside table. use class for background color and `addClass` to respective table rows

```js
$(function(){
$("#table_reach_condition_appoint tbody tr:odd").addClass('rowColor');
});
```

```css
.rowColor {
 background-color: #fde3e5 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table_reach_condition_appoint">
 <tr><th>Head 1</th><th>Head 2</th></tr>
 <tr><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2</td><td>2</td></tr>
 <tr><td>3</td><td>3</td></tr>
 <tr><td>4</td><td>4</td></tr>
</table>
```